# Writing to console and handle won't go together in Haskell

Tags: sockets, haskell

I've to create a network where I've a thread for every node that has a direct connection to the thread in the terminal. I need multiple terminals to create a big network to send message. To send messages I use sockets and handles.
But something went wrong first, the maps I use to store information go wrong (don't know why), when I tried to know why that went wrong I had the trouble of wanting to print something in the console to know what is the input of a function. But then the other program that was waiting for a message from the program that is getting the connection in handleConnection gets the line I wanted to put into the console and not get to a neighbour that was getting a connection to that program.
I've know idea why that other program gets that message.
Here's a part of my code:

```
listenForConnections :: Socket -> TVar (Map.Map IDnumber Location) -> TVar (Map.Map IDnumber Distance) -> TVar (Map.Map IDnumber Handle) -> IO ()
listenForConnections serverSocket nextnodeu distanceu maphandles = do
  (connection, _) <- accept serverSocket
  _ <- forkIO $ handleConnection connection nextnodeu distanceu maphandles
  listenForConnections serverSocket nextnodeu distanceu maphandles

handleConnection :: Socket -> TVar (Map.Map IDnumber Location) -> TVar (Map.Map IDnumber Distance) -> TVar (Map.Map IDnumber Handle) -> IO ()
handleConnection connection nextnodeu distanceu maphandles = do
  putStrLn "Got new incoming connection"
  printTVar nextnodeu
  chandle <- socketToHandle connection ReadWriteMode
  portnumberstring <- hGetLine chandle
  putStrLn portnumberstring
  let neighbour = read portnumberstring :: Int
  rn <- evaluate neighbour
  --putStrLn $ show rn
  atomically $ addTVarMap rn (Portnumber rn) nextnodeu
  --printTVar nextnodeu
  atomically $ addTVarMap rn 1 distanceu
  --printTVar distanceu
  atomically $ addTVarMap rn chandle maphandles
  --printTVar maphandles
  --hPutStrLn chandle "Welcome"
  message <- hGetLine chandle
  putStrLn $ "Incoming connection send a message: " ++ message
  value <- readTVarIO nextnodeu
  putStr $ show $ Map.size value
  putStrLn $ show rn
  _ <- forkIO $ listenToNeighbour nextnodeu distanceu maphandles chandle neighbour
  return ()
```

The many print/put statements are to get to know what goes wrong in the first place, but then I found another problem what I'm asking here.
Some of the error message that I got were:
`netchange.EXE: <socket: 564>: hGetLine: end of file` in the program that started to connection
and

```
fromList []
ConGnoetc tnienwg  itnoc onmeiinggh bcoounrn e1c1t0i2o.n.
.
```

From the program that was waiting for someone that wanted to connect.

Comment: Proposal to avoid `stdout` contention: write to a different file in each thread instead. You could use `myThreadId` to choose the name and not have to pass extra arguments.

Comment: @DanielWagner for what could this help? And what should stout contention be?

Comment: As a side note, it feels very weird to have a bunch of calls to `atomically` in a row, especially when it looks like they're updating related pieces of state. That seems like a great way to run into race conditions.

Comment: @JoesdeJonge You say, "I had the trouble of wanting to print something in the console to know what is the input of a function. But then the other program that was waiting for a message from the program that is getting the connection in handleConnection gets the line I wanted to put into the console". So, instead of printing to the console, write to a file.

Comment: ...but as it stands, I don't really think this question has what we need to answer it well. You should focus on just one problem per question, and you need at *least* a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.